# Click event oop

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I want to create a click event.

However, the value of console.log in controlCount () is different.

```js
function Spinbox() {
  this.MIN_COUNT = 180;
  this.MAX_COUNT = 220;
  this.$inputBox = $(`<input type="text"/>`);
  this.$increaseButton = $(`<button type="button">+</button>`);
  this.$decreaseButton = $(`<button type="button">-</button>`);
}

Spinbox.prototype.controlCount = function() {
  console.log(this.$inputBox.val());
  // not working. because this = <button type="button">+</button>
  
}

Spinbox.prototype.create = function() {
  this.$increaseButton.click(this.controlCount);
  $("#wrap").append(this.$inputBox);
  $("#wrap").append(this.$increaseButton);
  $("#wrap").append(this.$decreaseButton);
}
var spinbox1 = new Spinbox();
spinbox1.create();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrap">

</div>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to get the `val` of the button? Do you want the `text` of the button? `this.$increaseButton.text()`? That would just give you the + symbol.

Comment: sorry, mymistake. I modify my question

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is because within the scope of the click handler, ie. your `controlCount()` function, `this` will refer to the clicked button, *not* your `Spinbox()`.

To fix the problem you can turn `this` directly in to a jQuery object. However, note that neither button has a `value` attribute. Presumably this was an oversight, so I added it in this example:

```js
function Spinbox() {
  this.MIN_COUNT = 180;
  this.MAX_COUNT = 220;
  this.$inputBox = $(`<input type="text"/>`);
  this.$increaseButton = $(`<button type="button" value="increase">+</button>`);
  this.$decreaseButton = $(`<button type="button" value="decrease">-</button>`);
}

Spinbox.prototype.controlCount = function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
}

Spinbox.prototype.create = function() {
  this.$increaseButton.click(this.controlCount);
  $("#wrap").append(this.$inputBox);
  $("#wrap").append(this.$increaseButton);
  $("#wrap").append(this.$decreaseButton);
}
var spinbox1 = new Spinbox();
spinbox1.create();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrap"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is to use `jQuery.proxy()` helper in line when you assign the "click" event:

```
this.$increaseButton.click($.proxy(this.controlCount, this));
```

Read more about the `jQuery.proxy` in https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/. It will call the method with your `Spinbox` object as `this`.